# 2d mutable list populate - kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I am trying to fill the list below with strings, but I cannot figure out how to
set the variable `strings` to match the required type. I keep getting type mismatch.
(type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList but String was expected)

```
fun main() {
        val inputList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
        val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
        var strings: String 
            
        for (i in 0 until n) {
            strings = "D".toString().toMutableList()
            inputList.add(strings)
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired result is. Let's say, with n = 5, do you want `[["D"],["D"],["D"],["D"],["D"]]` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputList` is a list of lists. So you can only add lists to it. You defined `strings` as type `String` but you actually want it to be `MutableList<String>`. Furthermore, the `toString()` is useless because "D" is already a `String`, and also `toMutableList` turns a `String` into a `MutableList<Char>` of its characters. So what you want to do is:

```
val inputList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
var strings: MutableList<String>

for (i in 0 until n) {
    strings = mutableListOf("D")
    inputList.add(strings)
}
```

Though I would say it's unnecessary to first store it in `strings` so you can just do

```
val inputList: MutableList<MutableList<String>> = mutableListOf()
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()

for (i in 0 until n) {
    inputList.add(mutableListOf("D"))
}
```

or you can get the same result much shorter with

```
val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
val inputList = MutableList(n) { mutableListOf("D") }
```